# Is there a way to abort a test if the settings library setup fails?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a library management_utils.py that's something like:

```
path = global_settings.get_rdio_base_path()
if path == "":
     raise PathRequiredError("Path is required...")

def some_keyword():
     # keyword requires path to be set to some valid value
```

In my test case file I have something like:

```
***Settings***
Library     management_utils

***Test Cases***
Smoke Test
  some keyword
...
```

Is it possible to abort running these test cases if the management_utils setup fails? Basically I'd like to abort execution of these test cases if PathRequiredError was raised in management_utils.py.

When I run the tests, I see the error being raised but execution continues on.

I saw in the Robot documentation you can set ROBOT_EXIT_ON_FAILURE = True in your error class but this doesn't seem to work for this case. Also ideally I'd be able to do something more granular so that it only aborts the test cases that require this Library, not all test execution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the exception is raised during library loading, since it is in the top level of module. ROBOT_EXIT_ON_FAILURE only effects if the failure comes from a keyword.

Instead, do this:

```
def get_path():
    path = global_settings.get_rdio_base_path()
    if path == "":
        raise PathRequiredError("Path is required...")

def some_keyword():
   path = get_path()
   ...
```

Now the exception is raised inside a keyword, and the test execution will be stopped.

As for the other point, there's no way to abort just some tests using ROBOT_EXIT_ON_FAILURE.